# Seeding items with relations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Something { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Something { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my context, I want to seed some `Foo`s with related `Bar`s:

```
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo
    {
        Name = "Foo 1",
        Something = "Blah",
        Bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "Blah" },
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 2", Something = "Blah" },
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 3", Something = "Blah" },
        }
    },
    ...
```

If I run `Update-Database` everything works as you'd expect, and I get the related `Bar`s added for each `Foo`.

Now, if I go and change my seed data to something like:

```
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo
    {
        Name = "Foo 1",
        Something = "BlahBlahBlah",
        Bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "BlahBlahBlah" },
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 2", Something = "BlahBlahBlah" },
            new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 3", Something = "BlahBlahBlah" },
        }
    },
    ...
```

And run `Update-Database` again, the `Foo`s are updated, but all of the `Bar`s will still have "Blah" for their `Something` properties. This makes sense, since there's no logical way for Entity Framework to know which `Bar` should be updated, but is there any workaround? Perhaps some other way I can add the `Bar`s and also keep them related to the `Foo`s? I know I could simply do:

```
context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
    r = r.Name,
    new Bar
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
```

But given that I'm using identity columns as keys, I have no way to know which `Bar`s to add to which `Foo`s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your first method (question) and second method (answer) don't work for the second execution of Seed method.

**First Method**

```
Bars = new List<Bar>
{
    new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "Blah" },
    // new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 4", Something = "Blah" },
}
```

As you have known the second execution of the Seed method, if you modify `Something` to `BlahBlahBlah` the result will not save the modified `Bars` collection because it only updates scalar properties of `Foo`

While on first execution of `Seed`, `Foo` is a new entity and all objects underneath this graph will be marked as `Added` too.

Also if on the second execution of the Seed method, you add a new `Bar` (commented code) that refers to existing `Foo`, the new `Bar` will not be added too.

**Second Method**

```
var bar1 = new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "Blah" };
context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    bar1
);
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo
    {
        Name = "Foo 1",
        Something = "Blah",
        Bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            bar1
        }
    }
);
```

This is worse than the first method, the second execution of Seed method will throw exception, because when updating any `Bar`, it will try to update the relationship of `Bar` to un-found `Foo`, the `Bar's FooId` is not specified that means its value will be 0. `Foo` with Id equals to 0 is not found.

**Solution**

You need to define temporary key to be able to perform "Add or Update" correctly.

```
var bar1 = 
    new Bar { Id = 1, Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "Blah", FooId = 1 };
var bar2 = 
    new Bar { Id = 2, Name = "Foo 1 Bar 2", Something = "Blah", FooId = 1 };
var bar3 = 
    new Bar { Id = 3, Name = "Foo 1 Bar 3", Something = "Blah", FooId = 1 };
// var bar4 =
//     new Bar { Id = 4, Name = "Foo 1 Bar 4", Something = "Blah", FooId = 1 };

db.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    bar1,
    bar2,
    bar3
    // bar4
);

db.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Foo 1",
        Something = "Blah"
    }
);
```

The second execution of Seed method will update `foo's and Bars' Something` to `BlahBlahBlah`. And the new `Bar` (commented code) will successfully get added and refers to existing `Foo`.

More

- [Entity Keys and Added Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd283139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing the question it occurred to me that I could do it this way:

```
var bar1 = new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 1", Something = "Blah" };
var bar2 = new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 2", Something = "Blah" };
var bar3 = new Bar { Name = "Foo 1 Bar 3", Something = "Blah" };
...

context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    bar1,
    bar2,
    bar3,
    ...
);

context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    new Foo
    {
        Name = "Foo 1",
        Something = "Blah",
        Bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            bar1,
            bar2,
            bar3
        }
    },
    ...
);
```

However, I haven't had a chance to test this yet, and I'm still open to other ideas, regardless.